# What's a less obscure word for "sinecure"?

Tags: word-choice, phrase-requests, synonyms, antonyms

I'm writing a message which will go out to a global community, so I want to keep the vocabulary relatively straightforward. I'm describing a job which previously has been a little vaguely-defined, but which going forward is expected to be significantly more meaningful, both in responsibilities and impact.

In my draft, I wrote that the position is a serious one, "not a sinecure". However, this only really helpful if someone already knows this (relatively obscure, I think) word. I can, of course, *explain* more, but I was hoping for some thing succinct. The thesaurus is not helping here; is there another word or short phrase which concisely expresses the same or similar meaning?

Comment: Sinecure is essentially "title-only" or "meaningless but you get paid".

Comment: Btw, "sinecure" is essentially a metaphor, and not that obscure. You seem to need a direct term.

Comment: "This position is now better defined, and significantly more meaningful, both in responsibilities and impact." Sounds good to me.

Comment: Maybe a positive statement, such as *evolving*.

Comment: you will say that the job is ideal for challenge seekers. your ad is to entice good people, not dissuade lazy people.

Comment: Given that a *sinecure* is some sort of position without any actual work or responsibilities to speak of, the delight of loafers and slackers since time immemorial, it seems a little odd to be advertising a work position as one in which work will be done.

Comment: How do I apply? 

Answer (score 14):

I suggest  **[nominal](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/nominal)**:  (from TFD)

> - existing in name only.

The position is a serious one, not just nominal.

> - she is the *[nominal](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/nominal)* head of our college, the real work is done by her deputy.  (from Cambridge Dict,)

Answer (score 6):

You may be looking for something like

> [**gravy train**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/gravy+train)
>   *n*. *Slang*
>   An occupation or other source of income that requires little effort while yielding considerable profit.

or, stretching a bit further afield,

> [**make-work job**](http://encyclopedia.thefreedictionary.com/make+work)
>   [T]he phrase "make-work" is . . . used for work that is both of negative financial benefit and also not considered to be of any other particular benefit to the national interest.

[Links point to and quoted excerpts taken from thefreedictionary.com]

Comment: Both of these suffer from the fact that are unlikely to be more understandable to a ‘global community’ than sinecure.

Comment: Well, either of them is better than *nominal*, which is a poor force-fit.

Comment: Yes, probably, but I think *cushy* or (not) *demanding* could get the idea across more effectively and *sinecure* is still the best noun until now. At least you can find it in an English-something dictionary…

Answer (score 4):

**Figurehead** ([Collins English Dictionary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/figurehead))

> 1. a person nominally having a prominent position, but no real authority

What you are trying to say is that this was not a *figurehead position*, but has responsibilities and authority...(which I imagine you will go on to describe).

Answer (score 3):

The term *[cushy](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/cushy)* is often applied to sinecures

> (Of a job, task, or situation) undemanding, easy, or secure:
>   *cushy jobs that pay you to ski* [*Oxford Dictionaries Online*]

It is usually followed by *job, post, position* or similar reference to an assignment.

You are clearly trying to indicate that the job is **not** like that of *Co-ordinator of Inter-relations*, the ill-defined, ineffective position held by Mr. Nat, a character created by [Gene Klavan](http://www.blogofdeath.com/2004/04/12/gene-klavan/), a well-known radio personality in the 1960s.

Answer (score 1):

How about [demanding](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/demanding)? This word can have negative connotations, however, so you may want to qualify its use with a phrase like '...demanding and rewarding post...'.

Similarly: *challenging* or *engaging*.  Perhaps a phrase like 'This will be a *significant* and *engaging* role...'.